# Batch script to list all files on disk

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I would like to create a small batch file that lists me all on one disk file. The command is this:

```
TREE L: / F / A> List.txt
```

But I would like the user to enter the drive letter to be processed and the result is put into a file with the name and the current date. Example:

```
C:\> makelist.bat
Please, insert the drive letter: L
Done!
```

The result must be entered in a file named for example `List_2017-03-13.txt` and moved to the Desktop

What commands should I use to create the script?

Comment: Windows and DOS batch scripts are very different. Removed MS-DOS in the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following batch uses wmic to

- get a locale/user-settings independent date
- get a list of available drive letters
- and choice to select a letter

---

```
:: makelist.bat
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set Started=%date% %time%
:: get locale/user-settings independent date
for /f "delims=." %%A in (
  'wmic os get LocalDateTime^|findstr ^^[0-9]'
) do Set "DT=%%A"
Set MyDate=%DT:~0,4%-%DT:~4,2%-%DT:~6,2%

:: gather available drives
Set "Drives="
FOr /f "delims=:" %%A in (
  'Wmic logicaldisk get name^|findstr "^[A-Z]:"'
) DO Set "Drives=!Drives!%%A"

:: choose drive letter
Choice /C %Drives% /M "Select drive letter for tree"
Set /A "Inp=%Errorlevel%,Pnt=Inp-1"
IF %Inp% equ 0   Echo aborted & pause & exit /B 1
If %Inp% equ 255 Echo aborted & pause & exit /B 1
Set "Drive=!Drives:~%Pnt%,1!"

:: do the tree 
Echo %Started% Tree started
Echo Tree %Drive%:\ /F /A  "%UserProfile%\Desktop\Tree_%Drive%_%MyDate%.txt"
     Tree %Drive%:\ /F /A >"%UserProfile%\Desktop\Tree_%Drive%_%MyDate%.txt"
Echo %date% %time% done
timeout -1
```

Sample dialog:

```
Select drive letter for tree [C,D,E,G,H,K,M,N,P,Q,R,T,U,V,W,X,Z]?H
2017-03-13 14:17:05,45 Tree started
Tree H:\ /F /A "C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\Tree_H_2017-03-13.txt"
2017-03-13 14:17:13,70 done

Drücken Sie eine beliebige Taste, um den Vorgang fortzusetzen...
```

Answer (score 3):

tree2txt.bat:

```
@tree %1 / F / A > Tree_%1_%date.TxT
```

Usage: 
`tree2txt X:`

Result: tree of drive X:\ to a file named Tree_X_20170313.TxT

Note that date's output format is dependent on your local date formate settings (the yyyy-mm-dd and the other formats thing).